# How can I bring out a variable that has been saved inside a function in R?

Tags: r, function, return

I made a code that ask the user a name, but I want that my code save this name foverer (when I input "name1", the code should tell me what the user has enter in "name1"). Here is my code:

```
checknames <- function(){
  gamers <- c("Rebeca","Lucas","Mario")
  games <- c("3","1","3")
  scores <- c("200","100","205")
  table <- data.frame(gamers,games,scores)
  r=0
  name1 <- c()
  repeat{
    print("Name Player 1: ")
    name1=scan(,what="character",1)
    for(i in 1:length(gamers)){
      if(name1==gamers[i]){
        print("This player is already in the file. Would you like to change the name?")
        r=scan(,what="character",1)
      }
    }
    if(r==2){
      break
    }
    if(r==0){
      gamers=c(gamers,name1)
      name1 <- data.frame(gamers=name1,games="0",scores="100")
      table1 <- rbind(table,name1)
      print("Nice")
      break
    }
  }
}
checknames()
```

Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: How do you expect this to be called? `checknames()` the first time asks for the gamers, and then `checknames()` a second time returns the previously-identified names without asking again?

Comment: @Jiakai, did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is not returning anything at the moment, and it creates the same data frame with 3 rows every time you run it. If what you want is to upload the data frame with new gamers, then you need to use it as an input of the fucntion:

```
gamers <- c("Rebeca","Lucas","Mario")
games <- c("3","1","3")
scores <- c("200","100","205")
df <- data.frame(gamers,games,scores) ### a data frame with previously-registered users

checknames <- function(table){

  r=0
  name1 <- c()
  repeat{
    print("Name Player 1: ")
    name1=scan(,what="character",1)
    for(i in 1:length(gamers)){
      if(name1==gamers[i]){
        print("This player is already in the file. Would you like to change the name?")
        r=scan(,what="character",1)
      }
    }
    if(r==2){
      break
    }
    if(r==0){
      gamers=c(gamers,name1)
      name1 <- data.frame(gamers=name1,games="0",scores="100")
      table1 <- rbind(table,name1)
      print("Nice")
      break
    }
  }
return (table1)} ### returns the input df with an added row

df <- checknames(df)
```

By running this, you will be prompted to introduce a new name and, if it is not repeated, your df will be rewritten with the additional row.

Anything that happens inside of a function will not be permanent unless the function returns it and it is assigned.